# Laravel site accessible on /public/index.php/

Tags: php, laravel, apache2

As the title suggests, I set up a server with a Laravel project (only this project will run on the server).
The server is an Ubuntu Server 22, with php7.4, mariadb and apache2.
I configured the project inside `/var/www/html`, added the virtual host on apache2 and tested the various services and everything works fine.
But when I reach the site via browser all the routes are under the url `http://site_IP/public/index.php /...routes...`.

I then configured a .htaccess to make the site accessible under the url `http://site_IP/...routes...` but this doesn't happen and I keep accessing it under /public/index.php.

Do you have any suggestions or advice?

- .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this two methods.

**method 01**

remove htaccess from public directory and add it in outside public directory. then after add this line to your env file

```
ASSET_URL=https://your_project_url/public
```

**method 02**

upload all project files to www directory and symlink your project into html directory

Comment: Thanks....i've used the first method, and added the ASSET_URL under my .env file, but the project is accessible under `http://myip/public/` if i want remove the /public path i need some config?

Comment: no idea about that. how ever it should work